# Using replace function in a php string

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this PHP code:

```
 $onclick = "submitAndReloadArea($('order_history_block').parentNode, '" . $this->getSubmitUrl() . "');$('.note-list-comment').each(function(E){E.html(E.html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));});";
```

I get this error

> Invalid regular expression: missing /

I think it's about this line:

```
E.html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` gets interpreted as a line break, because your PHP string is using double quotes as delimiters - so the resulting HTML code will be

```
[…].replace(/
/g,'<br />'));});
```

So, make that `\\n` in your PHP string, and you should get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Use `$(this).html()` instead of `E.html()`.

---

You're using `.each()` wrong.

`E` is not a jQuery object so `E.html()` is actually failing. You're looking at the wrong error.

Per https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/, the anonymous function receives a key and value. If you `console.log(E);` then you should see a numbered list going from 0 to however many `.note-list-comment` elements get matched.

```js
$('.note-list-comment').each(function(E){
    console.log(E);
    console.log(E.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="note-list-comment">
</div>
<div class="note-list-comment">
</div>
```